# Django Rest framework as Single Sign On

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on, autologin, django-oauth

I have created DRF application with Django OAuth Toolkit (DOT) Rest Application with oAuth2 flow. I was planning to use these api's as Single Sign On (SSO). For javascript client it is working fine with "authorization_code" grant type which is returning me access token and refresh token and with those I can authorize and authenticate my javascript application.

But for another Django application I am stuck to do the same. It has its own user database and default authentication backend. I want to authenticate users with SSO user database and create a session on successful login into SSO application (DRF application in my case).

I want to achieve following:

1. In Django Application I click on login link.
2. It redirect me to SSO login page and ask me to provide user
   credentials.
3. On successful login I redirect back to Django application and land
   on dashboard page after auto login.

If anybody can spare some time and let me know if I am getting wrong anywhere it will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what's the actual question?

Comment: How can I auto login into my django application with authentication through DOT API

Comment: That's too large for stack. Ask a simple question.

Comment: Okay.. Can I share a session between two django apps? or another option will be setting up user database as a centralised database.

Comment: Django apps living in the same application can certainly share a session. You should use the database and user features that django provides as default. This "other" django application, well, it's just more python right? So if you want to change the way it works, just edit the python?